# Passing a QTreeWidget (or any other QWidget) to a Slot in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Can i pass in any QWidget, in my Case a Subclass of a QTreeWidget to a Qt Slot?
I need to get text from the QTreeWidget in a member function of parent. Just passing in a QString as extra argument with `connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(QString)), parent, SLOT(changePicture(QString)));` works fine, but now i want to pass in a subclassed QTreeWidget `ifxTreeWidget *tree = new ifxTreeWidget();` to `changePicture`. I changed the Signature of changePicture to take an `ifxTreeWidget` as argument and the mapping like:

```
QSignalMapper * signalMapper = new QSignalMapper(parent);

signalMapper->setMapping(tree, tree)
```

and tried to connect it like:

```
connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(QWidget)), parent, SLOT(changePicture(ifxTreeWidget)));

connect( tree, SIGNAL(clicked(QModelIndex)), signalMapper, SLOT(map()) );
```

but this leaves me with:

```
QObject::connect: No such signal QSignalMapper::mapped(QWidget) in...
```

Do i need to declare a Signal? How and where (if so)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your connect statement is wrong. Try this

```
connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(QWidget*)), parent, SLOT(changePicture(QWidget*)));
```

and then in the `parent` class

```
void ParentClass::changePicture(QWidget* widget)
{
  ifxTreeWidget* tree = qobject_cast<ifxTreeWidget*>(widget);
  if (tree) {
    // do something with the tree now
  }
}
```